# How to estimate the magnitude of least positive integer solution for Legendre-Diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity

We know that there is a famous theorem to determine whether there is an integer solution to the Legendre-Diophantine equation with three variables.

> **Legendre theorem of ternary quadratic form**
>
> The indeterminate (Diophantine) equation
>
> $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$$
>
> whose coefficients a, b and c are pairwise coprime integers,
> square-free and not all of the same sign, has a non-zero rational
> solution if and only if all following three congruences are solvable:
> \begin{align*}
>   u^2\,&\equiv-bc\pmod{|a|},\\
>   v^2\,&\equiv-ca\pmod{|b|},\\
>   w^2&\equiv-ab\pmod{|c|},\\
>   \end{align*}

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Legendre_theorem

However, I was baffled by a Legendre equation $x^2 + 5 y^2 = 4389 z^2$.

(ps: $4389=3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot19$)

With the help of the above theorem and software, we found **by error** that the Diophantine equation $\text{exists}$ a non-zero integer solution, but I applied the software again to search brutally, and found no solution less than $10000$.

[Edit]In the process of judging whether the congruence equation has a solution, I mistakenly think that Jacobian sign is equivalent to Legendre sign.

Now I want to know **how to estimate the magnitude of least positive integer solution** for this Diophantine equation?

Wolfram Mathematica code:

```
In[1]={JacobiSymbol[-a*b, Abs[c]],
       JacobiSymbol[-a*c, Abs[b]],
       JacobiSymbol[-b*c, Abs[a]]} /. {
           a -> 1, b -> 5, c -> -4389}

Out[1]={1, 1, 1}

In[2]=Solve[x^2 + 5 y^2 == 4389 z^2 && 0 < {x, y, z} < 10000, {
      x, y, z}, Integers]

Out[2]={}
```

**Edit**

$$x^2 + 5 y^2 = 20769 z^2$$

Thanks for Jagy's solution. I also want to know the magnitude between the least positive integer solution and the coefficient of the above Diophantine equation.

```
Solve[x^2 + 5 y^2 == 20769 z^2 && 0 < {x, y, z} < 100, {
   x, y, z}, Integers]

{{x -> 17, y -> 64, z -> 1}, {x -> 58, y -> 59, z -> 1},
   {x -> 82, y -> 53, z -> 1}}
```

Comment: $x^2+5y^2=4389z^2\Rightarrow x^2+5y^2\equiv0\pmod{11}$ and $x^2+5y^2\equiv0\pmod{19}$ and these congruences have both as only solution $(x,y)\equiv(0,0)$ It follows that $(x,y)=(209a,209b)$. Can this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, no, Legendre symbol
$$  (-20|11) = (-1|11)(5|11) = (-1|11)(11|5) = (-1|11) = -1 $$

If $x^2 + 5 y^2 $ is divisible by $11,$ it must be divisible by $121 = 11^2.$  Indeed,  writing
$$11^t \parallel a^2 + 5 b^2  $$
to mean $11^t | a^2 + 5 b^2  $ but not $11^{t+1} |a^2 + 5 b^2,  $
the exponent $t$ must be even. Writing $t=2 \tau,$ we must have
$11^\tau | a  $ and $11^\tau | b  $

You need to check each prime that divides one of the coefficients

from page 82, Corollary 1, in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms: if $abc$ is squarefree, while $ax^2 + b y^2 + c z^2$ is indefinite, such that there is a nonzero integer solution to $ax^2 + b y^2 + c z^2=0,$  then there is such a solution with $$|a|x^2 + |b| y^2 + |c| z^2 < 4 |abc|.$$ Note that allowing square factors in $abc$ would raise the size of the smallest solution.

IF
$$ x=101 u^2 -492uv -429v^2 \; ,$$
$$ y=188 u^2 +318uv +24v^2 \; ,$$
$$ z=3 u^2 +4uv +3v^2 \; , $$
then
$$ x^2 + 5y^2 = 20769 z^2 \; . $$
which gives infinitely many solutions, including some small ones.

More matrices of coefficients of $u^2,uv,v^2$ The first one gives
$$ x=17 u^2 -640uv -429v^2 \; ,$$
$$ y=64 u^2 +34uv +24v^2 \; ,$$
$$ z= u^2 + 5v^2 \; . $$

```
 17   -640    -85 transposed       17     64      1
 64     34   -320 transposed     -640     34      0
  1      0      5 transposed      -85   -320      5

101   -492   -429 transposed      101    188      3
188    318     24 transposed     -492    318      4
  3      4      3 transposed     -429     24      3

 26   -574   -826 transposed       26    193      3
193    532    259 transposed     -574    532      8
  3      8      7 transposed     -826    259      7

 58   -590   -290 transposed       58     59      1
 59    116   -295 transposed     -590    116      0
  1      0      5 transposed     -290   -295      5

 82    366   -858 transposed       82     53      1
 53   -270    -48 transposed      366   -270     -2
  1     -2      6 transposed     -858    -48      6
```

Umm. There are several solutions with $z=1,$  since

j

```
agy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./bingo_target
Input three coefficients a b c for positive f(x,y)= a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 
1 0 5
Discriminant  20
Target to be represented? 
20769
20769 = 3 * 7 * 23 * 43
 xbound  145
 ybound  65
 x = 143, y = 8 target 20769
 x = 143, y = -8 target 20769
 x = 142, y = 11 target 20769
 x = 142, y = -11 target 20769
 x = 137, y = 20 target 20769
 x = 137, y = -20 target 20769
 x = 118, y = 37 target 20769
 x = 118, y = -37 target 20769
 x = 113, y = 40 target 20769
 x = 113, y = -40 target 20769
 x = 82, y = 53 target 20769
 x = 82, y = -53 target 20769
 x = 58, y = 59 target 20769
 x = 58, y = -59 target 20769
 x = 17, y = 64 target 20769
 x = 17, y = -64 target 20769
20769 = 3 * 7 * 23 * 43
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still want to know how to estimate the magnitude of the least positive integer solution of the new equation.